# Unique solution to an Initial Value Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I'm trying to find if the solution of the following initial value problem is unique.
\begin{align}
y' &= 3  (y^{2/3})\\
y(0) &= 0
\end{align}
I have tried with local or global well posedness theorems but I don't understand how to apply them to this problem.
The answer I am supposed to give requires me to use these theorems somehow.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stackexchange. I've edited your question using Mathjax, which is how we write mathematics here. It's easy to learn: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: By the way, the additional parentheses you just added around the $y^{2/3}$ are really not necessary --- the rules of operation-precedence already say that you have to compute the exponentiated thing before multiplying.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I was just trying to make sure it was as clear as possible

Answer (score 0):

This is one where just guessing an answer helps. From the first equation, it sure looks as if $y = x^n$ might be a solution for some $n$, and doing out the algebra, it turns out that $y = x^3$ is actually a solution. But so is $y = 0$. So ... not a lot of uniqueness there.

Sometimes brute force instead of fancy theorems is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you, this makes it clearer. However, if I needed to explain this using the "fancy" theorems, how could I go about it. I think my problem is with the interpretation of the theorem or something.

Comment: I don't really *know* the fancy theorems, but ... maybe you're not supposed to use them. If I ask you to prove that $2$ is prime, I suppose you could bring in the Prime Number Theorem somehow, but it'd be silly, because it's a one-line computation that needs doing. Sometimes an example is just an example. This one is a pretty good one for remembering that "existence and uniqueness theorems DO have hypotheses, and not every innocent-looking equation satisfies those hypotheses."

Comment: If $y$ is a solution then $Ky$ is a solution if and only if $K = K^{2/3}$, that is, only for $K = 0$ or $K = 1$.

Comment: Thanks, Keba. Fixed. I needed more coffee before writing that. :)

Answer (score 0):

All solutions are given by
$$y(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & x \le L, \\
(x-L)^3, & x \gt L,
\end{cases}
$$
where $L \in [0, \infty]$. (For $L=\infty$, $y \equiv 0$; thanks to John Hughes for catching this case missing in an earlier version of this answer.)

One way to see that (rough sketch): Suppose $y(x_0) > 0$ for some $x_0 > 0$ and solve (using your fancy theorems, if you want to – but separation of variables will do just fine) backwards in time. This works until you hit 0, from where you can only continue with $0$ since $y$ is increasing and nonnegative.

Comment: True, I will edit the answer.

Comment: Sorry for being so confused about all this, but what you are saying is like John Hughes, that the solution is not unique, correct?

Comment: Yes. Their answer shows that there are at least two solutions, mine that there are infinitely many. Moreover, I believe that characterizing all solutions is interesting. That being said, if you are only interested in disproving uniqueness, given two different solutions obviously suffices.